# Create a new event soure in Windows Server 2008

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-event-log

I have added logging to a web application (using the Enterprise Library framework) so exceptions are recorded in the application event log. I have given the event has a source called "WebApp" but this isn't being recorded as the source doesn't exist.

Is there a way to manually add a new event source?  I have found some examples on stackoverflow but these require creating custom install applications so before I go down this road I'm wondering if there is a simpler method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the source in the code of your web application, using:

```
System.Diagnostics.EventLog.CreateEventSource("MyApp1", "Application");
```

[Source](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xz73e171.aspx)

Comment: Thanks.  I take it there isn't a way to do this from the server console?

Comment: Not that I know of i'm afriad

Comment: In that case I don't think there is. In to the code it goes.

Answer (score 2):

If you use PowerShell you can create the event source from the console like this:

```
[System.Diagnostics.EventLog]::CreateEventSource("MyApp1", "Application")
```

If you don't have it installed as a feature in WS 2008, you should.

Comment: Since your event source only needs to be 'registered' once, this would be the proper way to do it.  Once it's registered, you can then produce multiple events from this source, with different event ID's and descriptions, based on how the app behaves.